# Bytecode on Mac and Windows

Tags: java, bytecode

I just compiled helloworld program on mac and the generated bytecode from the jvm is totally different from the generated bytecode from windows jvm. I thought jvm generates same bytecode no matter on which OS you compile your java program since java is famous for its platform independence with its bytecode.
Please explain

Comment: No. Java is famous for being able to _run_ no matter which OS. Now, having said that - "_totally different_" bytecode produced by the same version of `javac` for the same code surprises me - would you mind posting the specific code and the generated bytecode from both platforms? (if it's approperiately short that is)

Comment: have you tried to run those two bytcodes on a single platform?

Comment: “totally different” according to which comparison method?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `javac` AFAIK does not take into account the OS it's compiling on, the runtime will take that into account when running. that would be very surprising indeed

Answer (score 4):

The bytecodes generated will depend on the version of the `java` compiler that you use.

> I thought jvm generates same bytecode no matter on which OS you compile your java program since java is famous for its platform independence with its bytecode

Nope.

The platform independence "guarantee" is that the bytecodes will *run* on any compatible Java platform.

- If you compile Java code with a Java 8 JDK and try to run on a Java 7 JRE, the chances are that it won't work.
- Even if your compile on the same platform with identical compilers, the ".class" files may contain timestamps and source code pathnames that differ between different compilations .... of the same source code.

But on the other hand, if I compiled using the Eclipse Java 8 compiler and specified Java 7 as the target version ... and I didn't use any Java 8 specific language features or APIs ... then my ".class" files should run on *any* Java 7, or Java 8 or Java 9 JRE.